# Waiting for element visibility instead of page load with Neustar WPM

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am trying to write a Neustar WPM script to measure the time taken from clicking a button to the appearance of a button in a overlay that opens. The script looks something like below.

```
var webDriver = test.openBrowser();
var selenium = webDriver.getSelenium();

webDriver.get('https://www.mywebsite.com');
selenium.waitForPageToLoad(30000);

// Start logging HTTP traffic and timings
test.beginTransaction();    

test.beginStep("Open SignUp");
selenium.click("link=Sign Up");
selenium.waitForElementPresent("name=nextStep");
test.endStep();

test.endTransaction();
```

The problem I am facing is that click does not return immediately and waits for the overlay to completely load. However I want to stop as soon as desired element is visible. How can I ensure that selenium.click return immediately instead of waiting till entire page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using this Java method,

`public WebElement waitForVisibilityOfElementLocatedBy(final By locator) {
        return waitFor(visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
    }`

```
public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> visibilityOfElementLocated(final By locator) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            try {
                return ExpectedConditions.elementIfVisible(ExpectedConditions.findElement(locator, driver));
            } catch (StaleElementReferenceException var2) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "visibility of element located by " + locator;
        }
    };
}`
```

Comment: I cannot use that code since I am relying on Neustar Scripting language is javascript based and gives access to the Java Selenium methods through Rhino.In any case, the main problem for me is that selenium.click doesn't return immediately to execute the next line. It waits till the entire page loading is completed which is not what I want. I want to click the link, wait for the next button to appear and stop.